# My HTML page does'nt see the controller and the node js request associed

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js

Here is my HTML code. I just have created a controller just for the part of the code.

```
<div class="mdl-grid" ng-controller="ValueController">
          <div class="mdl-card mdl-shadow--4dp mdl-cell--12-col">
              <div class="mdl-card__title">
                <h3 class="mdl-card__title-text">Modifier seuils sur la carte</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
              <div class="mdl-grid">
                <div class="mdl-cell--12-col mdl-grid">
                  <div class="mdl-cell--3-col mdl-grid">
                  <label class="mdl-cell--6-col">Plateforme</label>
                  <select class="mdl-cell--6-col" ng-model="platformselect" ng-change="obtainDatas()">
                    <option value="adsl">ADSL</option>
                    <option value="cable">Cable</option>
                    <option value="fibre">Fibre</option>
                    <option value="ott">OTT</option>
                    <option value="others">Others</option>
                    <option value="satellite">Satellite</option>
                    <option value="tnt">Tnt</option>
                  </select>
                 </div>
                  <div class="mdl-cell--3-col mdl-grid">
                  <label class="mdl-cell--6-col">Jour de la semaine</label>
                  <select class="mdl-cell--6-col" ng-model="dayselect" ng-change="obtainDatas()">
                    <option value="1">Lundi</option>
                    <option value="2">Mardi</option>
                    <option value="3">Mercredi</option>
                    <option value="4">Jeudi</option>
                    <option value="5">Vendredi</option>
                    <option value="6">Samedi</option>
                    <option value="0">Dimanche</option>
                 </select>
                 </div>
                  <div class="mdl-cell--3-col mdl-grid">
                  <label class="mdl-cell--6-col">Tranche horaire</label>
                  <select class="mdl-cell--6-col" ng-model="hourselect" ng-change="obtainDatas()">
                    <option value="0">0h-1h</option>
                    <option value="1">1h-2h</option>
                    <option value="2">2h-3h</option>
                    <option value="3">3h-4h</option>
                    <option value="4">4h-5h</option>
                    <option value="5">5h-6h</option>
                    <option value="6">6h-7h</option>
                    <option value="7">7h-8h</option>
                    <option value="8">8h-9h</option>
                    <option value="9">9h-10h</option>
                    <option value="10">10h-11h</option>
                    <option value="11">11h-12h</option>
                    <option value="12">12h-13h</option>
                    <option value="13">13h-14h</option>
                    <option value="14">14h-15h</option>
                    <option value="15">15h-16h</option>
                    <option value="16">16h-17h</option>
                    <option value="17">17h-18h</option>
                    <option value="18">18h-19h</option>
                    <option value="19">19h-20h</option>
                    <option value="20">20h-21h</option>
                    <option value="21">21h-22h</option>
                    <option value="22">22h-23h</option>
                    <option value="23">23h-0h</option>
                  </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="mdl-cell--3-col mdl-grid">
                  <label class="mdl-cell--6-col">Départements</label>
                  <select class="mdl-cell--6-col" ng-model='deptselect' ng-change="obtainDatas()">
                    <option value="0">01</option>
                    <option value="1">02</option>
                    <option value="2">03</option>
                    <option value="3">04</option>
                    <option value="4">05</option>
                    <option value="5">06</option>
                    <option value="6">07</option>
                    <option value="7">08</option>
                    <option value="8">09</option>
                    <option value="9">10</option>
                    <option value="10">11</option>
                    <option value="11">12</option>
                    <option value="12">13</option>
                    <option value="13">14</option>
                    <option value="14">15</option>
                    <option value="15">16</option>
                    <option value="16">17</option>
                    <option value="17">18</option>
                    <option value="18">19</option>
                    <option value="19">2A</option>
                    <option value="20">2B</option>
                    <option value="21">21</option>
                    <option value="22">22</option>
                    <option value="23">23</option>
                    <option value="24">24</option>
                    <option value="25">25</option>
                    <option value="26">26</option>
                    <option value="27">27</option>
                    <option value="28">28</option>
                    <option value="29">29</option>
                    <option value="30">30</option>
                    <option value="31">31</option>
                    <option value="32">32</option>
                    <option value="33">33</option>
                    <option value="34">34</option>
                    <option value="35">35</option>
                    <option value="36">36</option>
                    <option value="37">37</option>
                    <option value="38">38</option>
                    <option value="39">39</option>
                    <option value="40">40</option>
                    <option value="41">41</option>
                    <option value="42">42</option>
                    <option value="43">43</option>
                    <option value="44">44</option>
                    <option value="45">45</option>
                    <option value="46">46</option>
                    <option value="47">47</option>
                    <option value="48">48</option>
                    <option value="49">49</option>
                    <option value="50">50</option>
                    <option value="51">51</option>
                    <option value="52">52</option>
                    <option value="53">53</option>
                    <option value="54">54</option>
                    <option value="55">55</option>
                    <option value="56">56</option>
                    <option value="57">57</option>
                    <option value="58">58</option>
                    <option value="59">59</option>
                    <option value="60">60</option>
                    <option value="61">61</option>
                    <option value="62">62</option>
                    <option value="63">63</option>
                    <option value="64">64</option>
                    <option value="65">65</option>
                    <option value="66">66</option>
                    <option value="67">67</option>
                    <option value="68">68</option>
                    <option value="69">69</option>
                    <option value="70">70</option>
                    <option value="71">71</option>
                    <option value="72">72</option>
                    <option value="73">73</option>
                    <option value="74">74</option>
                    <option value="75">75</option>
                    <option value="76">76</option>
                    <option value="77">77</option>
                    <option value="78">78</option>
                    <option value="79">79</option>
                    <option value="80">80</option>
                    <option value="81">81</option>
                    <option value="82">82</option>
                    <option value="83">83</option>
                    <option value="84">84</option>
                    <option value="85">85</option>
                    <option value="86">86</option>
                    <option value="87">87</option>
                    <option value="88">88</option>
                    <option value="89">89</option>
                    <option value="90">90</option>
                    <option value="91">91</option>
                    <option value="92">92</option>
                    <option value="93">93</option>
                    <option value="94">94</option>
                    <option value="95">95</option>
                  </select>
                 </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border mdl-grid">
                <div class="mdl-cell--4-col mdl-grid">
                  <label class="mdl-cell--5-col">Valeur attendue</label>
                  <input class="mdl-cell--7-col" type="text" style="background-color: #66BB6A" ng-model="normalvalue"></input>
                </div>
                <div class="mdl-cell--4-col mdl-grid">
                  <label class="mdl-cell--5-col">Haute valeur</label>
                  <input class="mdl-cell--7-col" type="text" style="background-color: #FFA726" ng-model="highvalue"></input>
                </div>
                <div class="mdl-cell--4-col mdl-grid">
                  <label class="mdl-cell--5-col">Très haute valeur</label>
                  <input class="mdl-cell--7-col" type="text" style="background-color: #EF5350" ng-model="veryhighvalue"></input>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border mdl-grid">
                <div class='mdl-cell--12-col'>
                  <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent" style="float: right" layout-align="end center">Valider</button>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
        </div>
```

The controller i have created :

```
(function() {


angular.module('app').controller('ValueController', '$scope', ['forecastValue', function(forecastValue){

    $scope.obtainDatas = function() {

    forecastValue.getResults($scope.hourselect, $scope.dayselect, $scope.deptselect, $scope.platformselect)
      .then(function(report) {
       $scope.normalvalue = report.expected, $scope.highvalue = report.higherExpected, $scope.veryhighvalue = report.muchHigherExpected;
        }).catch(function(err) {
          $scope.result = '';
          console.error('Unable to fetch forecast report: ' + err);
          });
  };

}]);
})();
```

The forecast function to have the data :

```
(function(){

    angular.module('app')
    .factory('forecastValue', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){

        var apiAddr="https://something.com/app/getForecastDept";

        var forecast ={};

        forecastValue.getResults = function(hr, dy, dt, plm)
        {
            var httpParams = {
                hour: hr,
                day: dy,
                dept : dt,
                platform: plm
            };

            return $http.get(apiAddr, {
                params: httpParams,
                cache: true
            }).then(function(result) {
            return result.data;
            });

        };

        return forecast;

    }]);
})();
```

And there is the part of my node js code about this function :

```
app.get('/app/getForecastDept', function(req, res) {
  logger.info("GET /app/getForecastDept");
  if (req.query.hour && req.query.day && req.query.dept && req.query.platform){
    getForecastDept(res, req.query);
  } else {
    badCall(res, "getForecastDept");
  }
});
```

So when i launch the HTML page, i have have no function from the controller lauched. It is like if i have coded nothing.

How to explain this comportment ?

Comment: please provide more code via fiddle or plunker, because your code seems ok. While make sure you have `ng-app` directive applied to parent `<html>` tag and see your browser console for error.

Comment: In the console, i have this : http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.2/ng/areq?p0=ValueController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined

Yes i have an ng-app directive in a parent html element, just behind "doctype'.

Comment: have you included controller and factory files in script.

Comment: Yes, it is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make below changes:

1. when you create angular module, do it like `angular.module('app',[])` only first time, else it will override your module.
2. Inject `$scope` in your controller.
3. Your factory method needs to be part of return object.

See this basic [FIDDLER](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/28521/) to get clarity.

**Updated fiddler solution**
[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/x0sk62kn/9/)

Comment: I have "forecastValue is not defined"

Comment: have you changed `.controller('ValueController', '$scope', ['forecastValue', function(forecastValue){` to `.controller('ValueController', ['$scope','forecastValue', function($scope,forecastValue) {`. ? correct the injection. ?

Comment: then I recommend giving more details about your code in fiddle or plunker., because it should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: @SimonGirard: See this working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x0sk62kn/9/), you still need to define your api `getforecast` if not already.

Comment: The problem is solved. I had made a mistake in the recopy of your solution. Problem in the order of the parameters in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject `$scope` into your controller.

```
angular.module('app').controller('ValueController', ['forecastValue', function(forecastValue){
```

Becomes:

```
angular.module('app').controller('ValueController', ['forecastValue', '$scope', function(forecastValue, $scope){
```

And you need to actually call the function you defined in `ValueController`. Maybe at the end of your controller code, include:

```
 $scope.obtainDatas();
```

Comment: Done. I have "forecastValue is not defined" in the console. Why ?

Comment: Did you mean to declare and return `forcast` from your factory instead of `forcastValue`?

Comment: I have now : "forecastValue.getResults is not a function"